# MS Graph findMeetingTimes API not sorting meeting time suggestions correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

My problem is that the Microsoft Graph findMeetingTimes API is not sorting the meeting time suggestions like I would expect it.

In the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes#response) it says:

> If there are multiple meeting time suggestions, the findMeetingTimes
>   action first orders the suggestions by their computed confidence value
>   from high to low. If there are suggestions with the same confidence,
>   the action then orders these suggestions chronologically.

But whenever I try the API I get a "meetingTimeSuggestionsResult" sorted like this one:

- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 16:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 17:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 16:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 16:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 08:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 09:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 09:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 09:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 14:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 14:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 14:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 15:00:00
- Confidence: 50   || 24.08.2017 13:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 13:30:00
- Confidence: 50   || 24.08.2017 13:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 14:00:00
- Confidence: 50   || 24.08.2017 15:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 15:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 11:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 12:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 10:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 11:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 11:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 11:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 10:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 10:30:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 09:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 10:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 12:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 13:00:00
- Confidence: 50   || 24.08.2017 15:30:00 -> 24.08.2017 16:00:00
- Confidence: 100 || 24.08.2017 12:00:00 -> 24.08.2017 12:30:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is outdated. That's the way the API used to work, but it was changed and unfortunately the doc wasn't updated.

Instead of a simple sort chronologically, the API tries to be "smart" about how it orders the results. There are a number of factors that go into it, with a major one being the user's past behavior. Showing a tendency to meet at certain times of the day can up that in the ranking.